# Media Queries max-width & min-width difference and how to write the code for different devices

Tags: css, media-queries

what is the media queries define and how to define. And different between @media (min-width:px) and @media (max-width:px). how to set the value both of dimensions and different viewports.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to set media queries? This is how to do it in CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  /* Your styles here */
}
```

This targets screen sizes from 480px to a maximum of 979px (typically tablet portrait sizes). It can take a lot of arguments, such as device resolution, pixel ratio, media type (e.g. "print") etc.

You can also do it directly on the link, like so:
`<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 979px)" href="mystylesheet.css">`

Mozilla has some great documentation on media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: But i am set this media queries -- And how can i set inner Styles for tow different widths (480px and 979px) because they are two different values and two different view ports. how can i set two different viewpoint queries in one media queries

Comment: See my jsFiddle for examples: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/9gHC9/ Adjust the window to see the background change.